# converting time and find the difference

Tags: python

I have been given a task to find differences between time. I don't have a problem finding how much hours and minutes there are in that time. I am having trouble with subtracting them. I keep getting an hour and 50 minute difference for 12:55 and 13:05 which is wrong. Ive tried subtracting 40 so it could reconize 60 minutes in a hour but that changes the hours and minutes I think my problem is  that it dosent stop at 60 but i dont know how to fix that. If anyone could give me advise on getting that 10 minute difference using operations.

```
import math
numA = int(input("A departs at: "))
numAhours = numA // 100
numAminutes = numA % 100

numB = int(input("numB departs at: "))
numBhours = numB // 100
numBminutes = numB % 100

differenceH = math.abs = (numBhours - numAhours)
differenceM = math.abs = (numBminutes - numAminutes)
print(differenceH, differenceM)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take into account that time rolls over, So if the b minute is less than the a minute then you need to subtract once from the difference hours since we will have rolled over to the next hour but shouldnt count that as an hour. Also if the b minute - the a minute is negative, we need to add 60 minutes to find out the actual minutes in advance we are not the difference between the two.

lastly we need to think about if we move forward past midnight then we will end up with a negative number for the hours so we need to add 24 to get the difference.

This all is based on b being in the future of a

```py
numA = 2355 #int(input("A departs at: "))
numAhours = numA // 100
numAminutes = numA % 100

numB = 905 #int(input("numB departs at: "))
numBhours = numB // 100
numBminutes = numB % 100

differenceH = numBhours - numAhours
differenceM = numBminutes - numAminutes

if differenceM < 0:
    differenceM += 60
    differenceH -= 1
if differenceH < 0:
    differenceH += 24

print(differenceH, differenceM)
```